# problems installing shared management objects sql server

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I am trying install Shared management objects for sqlserver. I get the error message that sqlserver 2008 CLR types are not installed. I can see from control panel that sql server system CLR types (x64) are installed. Can anyone assist. I have googled this but nothing seems to help

Comment: In control panel, what is the version # of the system CLR types that are installed? It might not be 10.0.xxxx which would correspond to 2008. And you should be able to download various versions of the CLR types from downloads.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, did you tried this? :
https://support.solarwinds.com/Success_Center/Patch_Manager/Microsoft_SQL_Server_2008_System_CLR_Types_are_missing_during_installation